# when should --no-undefined flag be used for shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++, shared-libraries

Let us say that we have the following library dependencies (lib are shared libraries)

```
lib1    lib2    lib3   lib4
 |       |       |      |
 -------lib5    lib6-----
 |       |       |      |
lib7     |       |      |
 |       |       |      |
 -------exe--------------
```

I decided to build all libraries with `-fvisibility=hidden` and `-Wl,--no-undefined` compiler flags.

exe requires lib4, lib5, lib6 and lib7. It does not directly require lib1, lib2 and lib3.

lib1 is linked both to lib5 and lib7 but its symbols are hidden from exe because `-fvisibility=hidden` is used.

lib4 has to be directly linked to exe even though lib6 is already linked to it because `-fvisibility=hidden` hides all lib3 symbols that are used by lib6.

My question is if there is any reason not to use `-Wl,--no-undefined` flag with shared libraries in any of the above cases (or cases that I haven't thought of)?